# Can a C# WinForm app use a remote MySQL connection?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Is connecting to a remote MySql database through WinForms as simple as changing the connection string, or are there more steps required?

Comment: you could of course try this.....

Comment: Yup it is just as simple as that. Providing you can access the MySql database remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is connecting to a remote MySql database through WinForms as simple as changing the connection string

Yes, It is.

> or are there more steps required

And more steps are required such as allowing remote connections, getting through firewall if any. Proxy settings etc.